# How to specify to createfilew function get uncached result?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, filesystems

I need to check whether a file (on a remote server via `UNC path`) exists or not (permission is not a problem here; I make a required impersonation etc.).

I use [CreateFileW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) function for creating `file handle`.
I've also tried [GetFileAttributesEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesexw) but the behavior is the same.

```
HANDLE CreateFileW(
  LPCWSTR               lpFileName,
  DWORD                 dwDesiredAccess,
  DWORD                 dwShareMode,
  LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
  DWORD                 dwCreationDisposition,
  DWORD                 dwFlagsAndAttributes,
  HANDLE                hTemplateFile
);
```

If I deal with `UNC paths` I might get wrong result because of [UNC cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/ff686200(v=ws.10)) (different process copies or removes a file that I need to check).
It depends on `FileNotFoundCacheLifetime` registry key value (by default the value is 10 seconds).

```
// lets say I would like to check a file
// in the beginning the file exists
// than another process delete this file
// (e.g. executing drop database command by sql server)
// than another process copies this file back
// and all steps above takes less then FileNotFoundCacheLifetime value

// path = @"\\server\C$\Tmp\Folder\database\myDb.mdf"
private static void Test(string path)
{
    File.Exists(path);                              //exists
    Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));  //exists

    using (var handle = CreateFile(path, EFileAccess.GenericRead, EFileShare.Read, IntPtr.Zero,
        ECreationDisposition.OpenExisting, EFileAttributes.Normal, IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        if (handle == null || handle.IsInvalid)
        {
            //FileNotFoundCacheLifetime = 0  => exists
            //FileNotFoundCacheLifetime = 10 => Win32Exception - The system cannot find the file specified
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
        }
    }
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateFileW", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
    string lpFileName,
    EFileAccess dwDesiredAccess,
    EFileShare dwShareMode,
    IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
    ECreationDisposition dwCreationDisposition,
    EFileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    IntPtr hTemplateFile);

#region CreateFile
[Flags]
public enum EFileAccess : uint
{
    GenericRead = 0x80000000,
    GenericWrite = 0x40000000,
    GenericExecute = 0x20000000,
    GenericAll = 0x10000000,
}

[Flags]
public enum EFileShare : uint
{
    None = 0x00000000,
    Read = 0x00000001,
    Write = 0x00000002,
    Delete = 0x00000004,
}

public enum ECreationDisposition : uint
{
    New = 1,
    CreateAlways = 2,
    OpenExisting = 3,
    OpenAlways = 4,
    TruncateExisting = 5,
}

[Flags]
public enum EFileAttributes : uint
{
    Readonly = 0x00000001,
    Hidden = 0x00000002,
    System = 0x00000004,
    Directory = 0x00000010,
    Archive = 0x00000020,
    Device = 0x00000040,
    Normal = 0x00000080,
    Temporary = 0x00000100,
    SparseFile = 0x00000200,
    ReparsePoint = 0x00000400,
    Compressed = 0x00000800,
    Offline = 0x00001000,
    NotContentIndexed = 0x00002000,
    Encrypted = 0x00004000,
    Write_Through = 0x80000000,
    Overlapped = 0x40000000,
    NoBuffering = 0x20000000,
    RandomAccess = 0x10000000,
    SequentialScan = 0x08000000,
    DeleteOnClose = 0x04000000,
    BackupSemantics = 0x02000000,
    PosixSemantics = 0x01000000,
    OpenReparsePoint = 0x00200000,
    OpenNoRecall = 0x00100000,
    FirstPipeInstance = 0x00080000
}
#endregion CreateFile
```

Do you know how to get uncached result ?
Basically I can disable `UNC cache` I know about it.
Here I need a different approach - how to get uncached result precisely for a specific method call.

I know about the following approach - `$NOCSC$` (`@"\\server$NOCSC$\C$\folder\file"`) modifier but unfortunately it does not work on all operating systems.

`File.Exists()` and `Folder.Exists()` works but I need `fileapi` because it supports long paths (basically it's only one working solution).

Another good solution for me is cleaning UNC file system cache programmatically (again precisely before a specific method call).

Comment: File.Exists uses GetFileAttributesEx undercovers, no magic here, but it does nothing special with regards to the cache, so the fact you say "it works" is strange. Recent versions of Windows+.NET support long file names implicitely. Otherwise you can  prefix the path like `\\?\UNC\server\share` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file

Comment: I use this `\\?\UNC\server\share` UNC long path prefix for long network paths. .Net doesn't support all types of long paths(when you have more than 256 symbols for a one part of path - another words when a folder or a file name has lets say 1000 symbols )

Comment: Not sure I understand all you say, again, .NET is just using Windows native functions so why would it work any better? Also, what Windows file system has a file name component max length greater than 256?

Answer (score 1):

There is a fix for long paths (as per your comment to this post), at [blogs mdsn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/) and it is applicant for .net 4.6.2 and above.

You will have to add the application manifest file item to your project, there is a detailed guide in the blog for the process but all to all, it seems like a good solution to your issue without any necessary headache.

***In the example they do test it on Console Application, so you will have to figure how to make proper adjustments to your solution.***